# Ansible list of loop of loop

Tags: ansible

I've got a problem and not sure how to solve this properly. I wrote a module that creates fact of versions installed on the system. My goal is to get a list of change numbers included in the dictionary of the dictionary.

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************

```
    ok: [swsrv1-ccc01.localhost] => {
        "changed": false,
        "hostvars[inventory_hostname].version": {
            "version0217_1": {
                "change": "311",
                "Date_Deployed": "2016-11-17_11-07-08",
                "Defect": "NA",
                "Start_Date": "NA"
            },
            "version0217_11": {
                "change": "NA",
                "Date_Deployed": "2016-12-06_09-45-07",
                "Defect": "NA",
                "Start_Date": "NA"
            },
            "version0217_13": {
                "change": "NA",
                "Date_Deployed": "2016-12-06_09-45-14",
                "Defect": "NA",
                "Start_Date": "NA"
            },
            "version0217_15": {
                "change": "NA",
                "Date_Deployed": "2016-12-08_11-15-39",
                "Defect": "NA",
                "Start_Date": "NA"
            },
            "version0217_16": {
                "change": "1411",
                "Date_Deployed": "2016-12-13_16-45-42",
                "Defect": "NA",
                "Start_Date": "NA"
            },
            "version0217_17": {
                "change": "NA",
                "Date_Deployed": "2016-12-13_16-46-55",
                "Defect": "NA",
                "Start_Date": "NA"
            },  
            "version0217_19": {
                "change": "242",
                "Date_Deployed": "2016-12-19_13-29-37",
                "Defect": "NA",
                "Start_Date": "NA"
            }
        }
    }

    TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
    fatal: [swsrv1-ccc01.localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the key change should point to a list, got 'NA'"}
```

---

```
- debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname].version

- debug: msg="{{ item.1 }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].version }}"
    - change
```

My solution with_subelements just gave me one object but not as a list. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use `with_dict`:

```
- debug: msg="{{ item.value.change }}"
  with_dict: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].version }}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir. I did try this obviously the wrong way. I became the message "with_dict expects a dict" previously before without realizing I put it as as list.